# What to do without generating instances with "new"

Tags: c++

In some video games, I find that everytime a new character is created a factory method is used create the new one like this

```
class CharacterEngine
{
public:
   static Character* CreateCharacter(string Name, Weapons InitialWeapons)
   {
      return new Character(Name, InitialWeapons);
   }
};
//...
```

Now that if I have 100000000 characters (very many, e.g like simulated particles), heap allocation like this may fail to work on computers with small RAM. What is your solution to this problem?

**Edit**

What other methods or designs do you know can change or replace the factory method/class?

Comment: 100000 characters doesn't actually sound too scary for the heap, could you elaborate on what do you mean by "may fail to work"?

Comment: So please increase it up to 1m or more until it sounds scary.

Comment: What is the _actual_ problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I don't want to do what I'm doing as above. I need another way to create new Character without using *new*.

Comment: @OstrichGroomer: Don't comment your own question. But **edit your question** which needs a lot of improvement and explanation. Give the context and motivation of your question

Comment: I don't understand why a game would need to handle 100 millions characters. You should explain that in several paragraphs. What kind of game are you coding? What are these characters?

Comment: Your problem is not a C++ issue, it is a software architecture and design issue. You need to think and explain when would you have 100 millions characters, and you need to estimate their actual typical number (which should be much less)

Comment: How big are these objects? Are they homogeneous? How frequently are they created/destroyed? What are their lifetime requirements? Do you actually need *pointers* to these elements? Heap allocation is generally used because it allows you to "just ask for memory" and give it back when you are finished with decent all-around performance, if you want to use something different you have to analyze precisely what are your requirements to see what you can give up to gain what. If you want something that is exactly like `new` - well, use `new`.

Answer (score 4):

Do you actually have *100K* characters? And are you actually in an environment in which you are memory constrained and allocation fails? Even if `Character` is a whopping `1KB` in side, you'd be looking at `100MBs` consumed, which isn't *that much*, even for feature phones.

But perhaps you're worried that you might actually have memory to spare, but fragmentation is so high you can't use it. That's a fairer concern, and one usually relevant to games. Perhaps take a look at the [object pool](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html) pattern. Also, taking into consideration the large number of characters you're speaking of, perhaps [flighweight](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/flyweight.html) might also help!

Finally, running out of memory isn't like other program errors like losing a TCP connection or facing a disk error. If you *need* to allocate the `100001`th character and there's no more memory for it you can't not allocate it, show an error to the user or try again later. You can't go on without them as it were. So don't - just bail the program and perhaps do whatever cleaning up is required to not lose too much game state etc. Have a read for [malloc never fails](https://scvalex.net/posts/6/) as well.

Answer (score 2):

The heap memory is obviously limited, but the limit is in practice not that small (at least gigabytes on current PCs).

And memory consumption is not the biggest problem in a game. If you have many characters, you might need to deal with interactions between them, and that could be more difficult (e.g. determining the set of characters close to a given one could be more challenging).

You should read more about [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management), [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization), [circular reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference)s, [weak reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference)s, [hash consing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing).

Notice that the heap is *global* to your program & [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) (it is not the property of some particular class or code chunk, but of your entire program).

The heap allocation routines (related to [new & delete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_and_delete_(C%2B%2B))) are generally implemented about some [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) primitives (often [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call)) to grow the virtual address space. On Linux, see [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html). The operating system could provide some mean to query your virtual address space (on Linux, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and for a process of pid 1234, the `/proc/1234/maps` pseudo-file).

I recommend reading a good book on [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), such as the [*GC handbook*](http://gchandbook.org/). It teaches you concepts and terminology which are relevant for C++ programming (notably in games). In some sense, you may want to implement your own GC for your game.

C++ has some [allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) concept and standard [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) know about that.

Read also some [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms).

> heap allocation like this may fail to work on computers with small RAM.

Then either improve your program to use less memory, or get a bigger computer. Perhaps consider some [distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing) approach (e.g. [cloud computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing)), like in [MMORG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_role-playing_game).

> What other methods or designs do you know can change or replace the factory method/class?

They won't change much the consumed memory, because in your design every character is represented by its unique C++ object. So **that does not matter much**.

Comment: Thanks Basile, your post is awesome! =]]

Comment: But actually I still have no answer to my question yet. Instead of using a factory method like my OP, how do you think I can recode it yet to get the same or similar result?

Comment: That should go into your question. And you probably cannot recode a function, you might need to redesign your entire program and/or spend months in refactoring it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have enough local disk space to store the information of all characters, you can mmap one or more files that store all the character data, and create a character object from data in the file(s) only when needed.

If you have neither enough memory nor disk space to store data of all characters locally, then it becomes a much more difficult problem -- you might need to assign to every character an URI and load it from the network...

EDIT: Of course, after updating the character data, you'd need to write it back to the corresponding file. And for performance sake, you might want to implement some caching mechanism so frequently used characters don't need to be read & written back every time they are used.